# Поиск в базе данных SQLite без учета регистра русских символов в связке NestJS + TypeORM + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

В принципе это не вопрос, а ответ на него. Хочу поделиться опытом, потому что готового решения я не нашел. Идея - собрать свой драйвер better-sqlite с расширением ICU (International Components for Unicode). Данная БД быстрее SQLite и позволит решить поставленную задачу.

1. Скачиваем исходный код SQLite - https://sqlite.com/download.html
   Получаем папку sqlite-amalgamation-хххххх с файлами. В начало файла sqlite3.c пишем -

```js
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU 1
```

2. В файле проект packege.json добавляем

> ```
> {
>   "scripts": {
>     "preinstall": "npm install better-sqlite3@'^7.0.0' --no-save --build-from-source --sqlite3=\"$(pwd)/sqlite-amalgamation\""
>   }
> }
> ```

где в —-sqlite3 записываем абсолютный путь к папке sqlite-amalgamation-хххххх.

Так же убедитесь, что из "dependencies" удалено better-sqlite3.

3. Скачиваем исходные коды ICU - https://icu.unicode.org/download. Получаем папку icu-release-70-1 (70-1 версия, я эту использовал).
   Дальше, чтобы компилятор увидел эти файлы я скопировал в папку (для МаcOS)

- /Users/user/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/ все файлы (кроме папок unicode), находящиеся в
  icu-release-70-1/icu4c/source/i18n и icu-release-70-1/icu4c/source/common
- /Users/user/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/unicode содержимое из пропущенных папок unicode:
  icu-release-70-1/icu4c/source/i18n/unicode и icu-release-70-1/icu4c/source/common/unicode

4. В терминале из папки проекта пишем ‘npm install’. По окончанию все готово!
5. Немного поправить настройки проекта. В  файле app.module.ts:

```html
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'better-sqlite3',
        database: 'db-name.sqlite',
        entities: [],
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false  
    })
  ],   
  controllers: [AppController],  
  providers: [AppService], }) 
export class AppModule {}
```

6. Придется пожертвовать удобством TypeORM. Если бы раньше написали так:

```js
 this.filesRepository.find(
            {
                select: {
                    keeper: {
                        lastName: true,
                        firstName: true,
                        middleName: true
                    },
                    paragraphs: {
                        period: true
                    }
                },
                relations: 
                {
                    keeper: true,
                    paragraphs: true,
                },
                take: 500,
                order: {
                    id: "DESC"
                }
            })
```

То теперь придется написать так (это тоже TypeORM!):

```js
   this.filesRepository.createQueryBuilder('files')
            .leftJoin('files.keeper', 'keeper')
            .leftJoin('files.paragraphs', 'paragraphs')
            .select(['files', 'keeper.lastName', 'keeper.firstName', 'keeper.middleName', 'paragraphs.period'])
            .orderBy('files.serialNumber', 'DESC')
            .take(500)
            .getMany()
```

Сам поиск по полю serialNumber (например):

```js
this.filesRepository.createQueryBuilder('files')
            .where(`files.serialNumber Like '%${filters.serialNumber.trim()}%'`)
```

Или

```js
this.filesRepository.find({
            where: {
                serialNumber: ILike(`%${filters.serialNumber.trim()}%`),
            }
```

Есть еще небольшие отличия, не относящиеся к данной теме, но упомяну:
вместо relations: {joinTable: true} нужно relation([‘joinTable’])
вместо select: {name: true} нужно select([‘name’])

Удачи!

Comment: а вот так ищет? `select 1 from tablename where lower("serialNumber") like lower('%ваш_поиск%')`

Comment: Перевел данный запрос на TypeORM и так ищет:         this.filesRepository.createQueryBuilder('files')
            .select('files.serialNumber')
            .where(`LOWER(files.serialNumber) LIKE LOWER('%${filters.serialNumber}%')`)
            .getMany()

Comment: или так:         this.filesRepository.createQueryBuilder('files')
            .select('files.serialNumber')
            .where(`files.serialNumber LIKE '%${filters.serialNumber}%'`)
            .getMany()

Comment: данные коменты почему-то не отображают стильку - обратную кавычку. Все что в скобках у where находиться в стильках